# Etags used in RESTfull APIs are commonly described as hashes

Tags: python, database, rest, etag

So I've read a few articles about using Etags in RESTfull APIs and the vast majority of them say the Etag header should be a hash of the resource/entity/object, this seams wasteful.

Using a hash: A request comes in with a given Etag, the resource needs to be fetched (normally from a database) then it needs to be hashed using MD5/SHA/whatever and the result compared with the Etag, this takes time and CPU.

The Etag could be stored in the database as another column of the row (updated alongside any normal row update) so that it doesn't have to be computed for every request then in the SELECT query you can filter by WHERE entity.etag==etag. This means that the Etag has to be generated out of band from the database and in the client to the database, which is a bit limiting.

If you are storing it in the database then u might as well just use the last updated time, which is a native database functionlaity (nornally) and requires no extra processing (hashing).

Why is it suggested to use hashes?

Comment: Is there a question hidden in here somewhere, or did you just want to share your thoughts with us?

Comment: The original purpose of the etag is to safe bandwidth by just returning a 304 when a resource is requested again and has not changed. It was not intended to save processing time on the server. A clever implementation can do that as well, but for the original plan a hash is a good choice.

Comment: @Klaus D That is understandable,  but it seems illogical to increase processing time/resource consumption by using hashes to save bandwidth when there are better (?) alternatives to hashes? I guess hashes would solve the somewhat weird senario were the client was updating a resource with the same/unchanged values causing the last update time to change,  invalidating all Etags.

Comment: I explained the "why". A discussion on what a more clever implementation would be, is unluckily outside of the scope of SO.

Comment: You explained the "why use etags" not the "why use hashes" ;) nitpicky but valid.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are not reliable Etags, because two different updates could get to the database with the same timestamp.  A client could get version 1, and later miss version 2 because it had the same Etag.

Cryptographic hashes are better, because every different update will have a different hash.  As a bonus, identical updates will have the same hash.

It's not really necessary to hash the content, though -- any unique identifier will do.  A lot of systems have the database generate a unique ID for every update, and this ID will become the Etag.

Comment: The DB-generated unique ID is enough.  A cryptographically random ID is good enough, too  (some people use uuidgen, which is fine).  Crappy random IDs are not.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are suggested because the ETag should chance when the underlying resource changes. Historically, hashes are a representation of the actual content, so it's an easy solution to the problem.

You can mitigate the cost of hashing by caching the hash with the resource.

The idea of a unique ID is valid, just not the primary key. The ETag needs to change every time that the resource changes, a primary key does not. But the nice nature of a hash is that if you change the resource to something, and then change it back (i.e. undo the change), the hash will (typically) revert back to what it was, so anything that "missed" the intervening change, will effectively not see it (since their older ETag is still valid).

The Timestamp is valid for slow changing resources. Timestamps can be quite high resolution. But it suffers similarly from the same issue as the unique generated ID in terms of the ETag having no actual tie to the content itself.